# AnySoftKeyboard : Could not HEAD 'play-publisher-2.0.0-beta1.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Tags: java, android, gradle, keyboard

Every time when I am syncing open-source android project(AnySoftKeyboard) that i have downloaded from github, i am getting following compile error

```
   org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/triplet/gradle/play-publisher/2.0.0-beta1/play-publisher-2.0.0-beta1.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

As i have checked the URL manually it's asking for the credentials so can anyone help me to resolve this issues please

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research about it i got to know that it's an issue related to Automatic Gradle Play Publisher API/library so i have commented it in my project's gradle file.

So it's been resolved.